# ListWheelScrollView with physics of FixedExtentScrollPhysics scrolls too far on the web side

Tags: flutter, scroll

The code works well in phone, however, the scroll distance is too large to select what item I want when I use mouse to scroll.

`SizedBox( height: 240.h, child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate( controller: scrollController, physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(), itemExtent: 30.h, perspective: 0.01, useMagnifier: true, magnification: 1.6, diameterRatio: 1.2, overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5, onSelectedItemChanged: widget.whenSelectedItemChanged, childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate( childCount: widget.count, builder: widget.itemBuilder, ), ), )`

Is there a solution?